# How to move files within the Hadoop HDFS directory?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I need to move the files from one HDFS directory to another HDFS directory.

I wanted to check if there's some easier way (some HDFS API) to achieve the same task, other than InputStream/OutputStream ?

I've heard of `FileSystem.rename(srcDir, destDir);` but is unsure if this will delete the original src directory.

I don't want to remove the original directory structure, only move the files from one folder to another directory.

e.g

```
input Dir - /testHDFS/input/*.txt
dest Dir - /testHDFS/destination
```

After moving the files, directory should look something like this :-

```
input Dir - /testHDFS/input
dest Dir - /testHDFS/destination/*.txt
```

PS : I want to achieve this working inside mapper function for each file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileSystem.rename will move the file from source to destination directory. I believe you can use it for your requirement.

Comment: Will renaming the directory remove my original directory ? I don't want to delete that structure.

Comment: How to achieve this using python script. I need to rename the file system directory.? Is there any way in python other than -mv

Comment: `rename()` just re-links, and will fail if your source and destination dirs are on different volumes (without any explanation). Instead, use [FileUtil.copy](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html) with `deleteSource=true`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html), setting the `deleteSource` parameter to `true`. People commonly use `FileSystem.rename()`, but that function will fail silently for invisible issues ([such as the source and destination Paths being on different volumes](https://community.mapr.com/thread/7415))

Answer (score 0):

You can use DistCp programmatically [verify this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-tools/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.java)